# setuid upstart not working

Tags: node.js, upstart, init

I have created a .conf file in which I include

```
    setuid mario
    setgid mario
```

in order to run as mario user.
The program I run in the exec command is forever which runs an instance of node which inside spawns cvlc. cvlc does not permit to be executed as root.

With this configuration "sudo start myapp" does not start.

I'm using upstart 1.5.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look in your logs and at least add relevant log lines to your question.

Comment: The console just logs: "start: Job failed to start"

Comment: Finally I got it through su

        exec su -s /bin/sh -c 'exec {COMMAND}' {USER}